# Joyent : deploy with git

Tags: git, node.js, deployment, joyent

I have a Joyent SmartMachine with node.js installed.
How do I deploy my apps using git?

I couldn't find any docs on that matter, mostly because they are outdated since Joyent no longer supports it no.de service.

Thanks.